# TypeORM - update nested entities, Typescipt issue

Tags: typeorm

I have a Call entity that contains a user with a ManyToOne relation (and some other irrelevant fields).

So, the entity looks like that:

```
@Entity()
  export class Call extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToOne(() => User, {cascade: true, eager: true})
  user: User;
}
```

I want to update that Call so it will be connected to userId 1 (for example).

When I am trying to update the call with other userID - I am getting a TypeError:

```
Call.update({ id: 1 }, { user: 2 })
```

(Because type number is not from type User)

What is the best way of doing that (without using "any")?

Answer (score 0):

Should be
`Call.update(1, { user: { id: 2, ...other props } })`